# redirect to specific page based on db value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form which is like the login form ,,, the idea is the user enter his first name and last name and I need to check if the gender is male it will redirect to a male.aspx and if the gender is female it will redirect to female.aspx, and if firstname and lastname are wrong or not match or not exist he will go back to the same form again.

I did the main code but I don’t know how to check gender to redirect to the page

Also I want to show the full name (First & last name) in the next page.

Here is my code. Hope I get help.

```
protected void log_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource sds = new SqlDataSource();
    sds.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDbConnectionString1"].ToString();
    sds.SelectParameters.Add("firstname", TypeCode.String, this.firstname.Text);
    sds.SelectParameters.Add("lastname", TypeCode.String, this.lastname.Text);
    sds.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [myTb] WHERE [firstname] = @firstname AND [lastname] = @lastname";
    DataView dv = (DataView)sds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    if (dv.Count == 0)
    {
        this.lblmsg.Text = "Invalid firstname and lastname!";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try it
After storing the data in the dataview access the gender column as

```
    string gender = dv.Table.Rows[0]["gender"].ToString();
    if (gender == "male")
    {
          Response.Redirect("malepage.aspx");
    }
    else if( gender == "female" )
    { 
          Response.Redirect("femalepage.aspx");
    }
```

In order to get First and last name use this

```
 string fname= dv.Table.Rows[0]["firstname"].ToString();
 string lname= dv.Table.Rows[0]["lastname"].ToString();
```

You can pass these to the second page by using querystring  or Session.

```
Response.Redirect("yourpage.aspx?fname="+fname+"lname="+lname);

// on second page get them as
string fname = Request.QueryString["fname"];
string lname = Request.QueryString["lname"];

// or by using session pass these values as
Session["fname"] = fname;
Session["fname"] = lname;

// and on the second page get them as
string firstname = Session["fname"].ToString();
string lasttname = Session["lname"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (System.Convert.ToString(dv.Table.Rows[0]["colName"]) == "Male")
{
Response.Redirect("~/Male.aspx");
}
else
{
Response.Redirect("~/female.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
if(dview.Table.Rows[0]["Gender"].ToString() =="Gender")
{
Response.Redirect("Page.aspx?fname="+dview.Table.Rows[0]["fname"].ToString()"&LastName=" + dview.Table.Rows[0]["lname"].ToString());

}
else
{
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?fname="+dview.Table.Rows[0]["fname"].ToString()");
}
```

Send First Name and Last Name in a querystring and join them in the destination page by `Request.Querystring`